# Css background: offset for repeating-linear-gradient

Tags: css, sass, repeating-linear-gradient

I have drawn a grid as a repeating background of a `<div>` the following way in SASS:

```
background-image:
  repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, $major-grid-color, $major-grid-color $major-grid-weight, transparent $major-grid-weight, transparent $major-grid-size),
  repeating-linear-gradient(-90deg, $major-grid-color, $major-grid-color $major-grid-weight, transparent $major-grid-weight, transparent $major-grid-size),
  repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, $minor-grid-color, $minor-grid-color $minor-grid-weight, transparent $minor-grid-weight, transparent $minor-grid-size),
  repeating-linear-gradient(-90deg, $minor-grid-color, $minor-grid-color $minor-grid-weight, transparent $minor-grid-weight, transparent $minor-grid-size);
```

It renders the following way:

[image: Bad]

But I want it to render with an offset of `15px` to the left (or an offset of `4 * $minor-grid-size + 15px` to the right), ie:

[image]

Now I can't use `margin-left`, because it will also offset the elements inside of the `<div>` tag and I don't want that, [see the Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/LoveMetal/Lr2hnfbk/33/) (don't pay attention to the JS).

I only want the background to have an offset.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might use `background-position` property.

```
.repeating-grid {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  background-size: $major-grid-size $major-grid-size;
  background-image:
    repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, $major-grid-color, $major-grid-color $major-grid-weight, transparent $major-grid-weight, transparent $major-grid-size),
    repeating-linear-gradient(-90deg, $major-grid-color, $major-grid-color $major-grid-weight, transparent $major-grid-weight, transparent $major-grid-size),
    repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, $minor-grid-color, $minor-grid-color $minor-grid-weight, transparent $minor-grid-weight, transparent $minor-grid-size),
    repeating-linear-gradient(-90deg, $minor-grid-color, $minor-grid-color $minor-grid-weight, transparent $minor-grid-weight, transparent $minor-grid-size);

  background-position: 15px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with a negative `background-position` causing the end of the repeating pattern to be cut off:

```css
background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, red, red 200px, blue 200px, blue 400px);
background-position: -50px -50px;
```

[image: background-position]

I found that using negative offsets in `repeating-linear-gradient` fixed the problem:

```css
background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, red -50px, red 150px, blue 150px, blue 350px);
```

[image]